# error "Unable to load vocabulary from file" when loading spacy "fr_dep_news_trf" model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I can't load the fr_dep_news_trf model with spacy.

```
nlp = spacy.load('fr_dep_news_trf')
```

It raises a "Unable to load vocabulary from file" error.

The model has been installed with the command

```
python -m spacy download fr_dep_news_trf
```

and install was successful

Version info :
spaCy version : 3.0.6 / Python version   3.7.8 / Pipelines fr_dep_news_trf (3.0.0)

Comment: Maybe the model download or install is corrupted. Uninstall the model package (`pip uninstall fr_dep_news_trf`) and try downloading it again without using any local cached copies (`spacy download fr_dep_news_trf --no-cache-dir`).

Comment: @aab you should write your tip as an answer so i can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model download or install is probably corrupted. Uninstall the model package (`pip uninstall fr_dep_news_trf`) and try downloading it again without using any local cached copies (`spacy download fr_dep_news_trf --no-cache-dir`)